# How to implement Serial communication using Android bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-communication

I have gone through the BluetoothChat code in Android documentation. But it seems so difficult to understand. I could not find any tutorials also based on this.

I want to send a string to a bluetooth device. The application has to scan for devices and connect to the selected device to pass the string.

Please help.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better use amarino library. i think this is what you are looking for.